# Receiving corresponding OSM raster tiles of .tfw files

Tags: python, raster, openstreetmap, geotiff-tiff, world-file

I have a bunch of handdrawn map plans, referenced with .tfw files, and I need their corresponding geographical map of that exact part of the world as a raster image to compare to.

With the solutions that I found you only get to define starting x and y coordinates and the zoom level of the map your are referring to, but that isn't accurate enough for me. What I need is to define a bounding box via longitude and latitude and get only that as a raster image.

Is there a library, preferably in python, that offers this kind of functionality?

to illustrate, the function would be something like:

```
writeOSMRaster("C:/*/*/*.png",[11.189816154513968, 11.193589850095204, 53.42800434704876, 53.4292907361823])
```